# cakephp fields of selected tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My code in controller looks as :

```
public function leftsidebar(){
        $this->layout=false;
        $productlist = $this->Product->Category->find('all');
        pr($productlist);
        $this->set(compact('productlist'));
        $this->render('leftsidebar');
    }
```

it outputs as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Cat New Name
                    [image] => Cat New Name_9547.jpg
                    [description] => Description  heeeererer
                    [active] => 1
                    [created] => 2015-02-17 12:07:43
                )

            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [productname] => CCTV products
                            [sortorder] => 0
                            [productimage] => CCTV products_4939.jpg
                            [description] => Some Description for product goes here
                            [created] => 2015-02-17 02:00:48
                            [modified] => 2015-02-17 02:00:48
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [productname] => Product Name
                            [sortorder] => 0
                            [productimage] => Cat Names _23749.jpg
                            [description] => Description
                            [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Name
                    [image] => Cat New Name_13850.jpg
                    [description] => Description 
                    [active] => 0
                    [created] => 2015-02-17 12:18:18
                )

            [Product] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Now from Product table i need only selected fields as id,category_id,productname and from category table only id and name,
So how can i achieve it .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> In Cakephp fields is the property where you can define your table fields name, if you want to define all the fields you use * operator with Model name such as Product.*. below is your code please check this

```
     public function leftsidebar(){
            $this->layout=false;
            $this->loadModel('Category');
            $productlist = $this->Product->Category->find('all',
            'fields' => array('Product.id', 'Product.category_name','Product.name', 'Category.id', 'Category.name')
            );
            pr($productlist);
            $this->set(compact('productlist'));
            $this->render('leftsidebar');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass a fields array in find function. You must have set model relations to use below trick.

```
public function leftsidebar(){
        $this->layout=false;
        $productlist = $this->Product->Category->find('all', array(
"fields" => array("Product.id", "Product.category_name","Product.name", "Category.id", "Category.name")
));
        pr($productlist);
        $this->set(compact('productlist'));
        $this->render('leftsidebar');
    }
```

For the run time relation, please see contain behavior of CAKEPHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass 2nd param to find method :

```
    $fields = array("Product.id", "Product.category_name","Product.name", "Category.id", "Category.name");
    $productlist = $this->Product->Category->find('all',$fields);
```

And carry on with your regular code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Product->Category->find('all',array(array("Product.id", "Product.category_name","Product.name", "Category.id", "Category.name"););
```